# How do I retract an upvote?

Tags: support

I know that I did not like it too much as it happend without explanation to me; but I promise that I will leave a corresponding comment. The comment is actually already there ...

So my question is do I have to click the upward arrow again or do I have to click the downward arrow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You click the up-arrow again.

However, you will not be allowed to retract a vote after a relatively short time unless the post has been edited in the interim (there was a problem with people gaming the voting system on Stack Overflow that resulted in this policy).

You are also asked not to edit a post solely so that you can retract a vote, though editing for that purpose is condoned if you substantially improve the post in some way.

Comment: Thanks @dmckee, I did not have to edit the post; it was edited by the OP such that I do no longer like it that much ...

Comment: Specifically, that "relatively short time" is 5 minutes. See [this Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187471/how-to-revoke-an-upvote)